# Calculating a basis of vector space $U \cap V$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

So I have two vector spaces:
$ U := \langle(1,2,1,2), (1,2,3,3), (1,2,2,3)\rangle $ and
$ V := \langle(2,0,2,1), (3,2,3,2), (0,4,0,1)\rangle $

I was able to calculate the base of both $U$ and $V$:
$ B_U = \langle(1,2,1,2), (1,2,3,3), (1,2,2,3)\rangle $ since the vectors linearly independent.
$ B_V = \langle(2,0,2,1), (3,2,3,2))\rangle $ since you can write
$(0,4,0,1)$ as $2*(3,2,3,2) - 3*(2,0,2,1)$.

However, I have no clue for to do it for $U \cap V$. Could you please point out how to go about doing that and/or giving me an example?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your $B_V$ incorrect?

Comment: Now it is, sorry.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25371/how-to-find-basis-for-intersection-of-two-vector-spaces) also helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there must be some overlap, since $U$ is $3$-dimensional and $V$ is $2$-dimensional.  So, either $V\subseteq U$, or they intersect in a one dimensional subspace.  Can you write both basis vectors of $V$ in terms of the basis for $U$?  If not, then the intersection is one-dimensional.  I'd just look at what vectors are in $U$ and $V$.  For instance $(0,0,2,1)$ and $(0,0,1,0)$ are in $U$.  Thus $(0,0,0,1)$ is also in $U$.

Comment: I found the basis of $U \cap V$ to be $(1,2,-1,1)$ - would that be correct?

Comment: @Jenox I get $(1,2,1,1)$.