# Linear algera-Question on Isomorphism.

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Can someone help me to solve the question of isomorphism [image]

I cannot gain an intuitive feel on it,because I cannot visualize $\mathbb C^3(\mathbb C)$.I am in problem with mainly the $2nd $ part of the problem because I cannot canculate $W_1 \cap W_2$.

Comment: What's $\Bbb C^3(\Bbb C)$?

Comment: vector space of complex triplets over complex field.

Comment: @Gae.S. the $\Bbb C$ in parentheses is there to emphasize that the scalars for this space are complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows: let $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \Bbb C^3$ be a non-zero vector solving the system
$$
x_1 + 0x_2 + ix_3 = 0\\
-2 x_1 + (1+i)x_2 + 0x_3 = 0
$$
Then the image of $W_1$ under the isomorphism is the solution space of vectors $z = (z_1,z_2,z_3)$ satisfying $x_1z_1 + x_2z_2 + x_3 z_3 = 0$.

Similarly, find a vector $y$ such that the image of $W_2$ is the solution space of vectors $z$ satisfying $y_1 z_1 + y_2 z_2 + y_3 z_3  = 0$.

The intersection of the images of $W_1$ and $W_2$ will be the set of vectors $z$ satisfying both equations.  That is, the image of $W_1 \cap W_2$ is the solution space to the system
$$
x_1z_1 + x_2z_2 + x_3 z_3 = 0\\
y_1 z_1 + y_2 z_2 + y_3 z_3  = 0
$$

---

Following the method that I outline [my post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/802878/81360) yields a different approach. Row reducing the matrix whose columns are $T(\alpha_1),\dots,T(\alpha_4)$ yields
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&-i&0\\
0&1&\frac{1-i}2&0\\
0&0&0&1
}
$$
Which is to say that the only non-trivial relation between these vectors is 
$$
-i T(\alpha_1) + \frac{1-i}{2}T(\alpha_2) = T(\alpha_3).
$$
Thus, $T(\alpha_3)$ forms a basis for the intersection of the images of $W_1$ and $W_2$.  Thus, $\alpha_3$ forms a basis the intersection of $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Comment: yes but it is hard enough to compute due to irrational coefficients.

Comment: Following this method yields $x = (-i, -1 - i, 1)$ and  
$$
y = (1 - 3\sqrt 2 + i (3 + \sqrt{2}), -2 - 3\sqrt 2 + i (3 + \sqrt 2), 3).
$$
I agree that that's pretty terrible.  If I think of a different approach, I'll let you know

Comment: Following the method [that I outline here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/802878/81360) should work as well

Comment: See my latest edit. The answer is the span of $\alpha_3$.