# Finding span of intersection of two vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was trying to follow [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25373), but as the comment to that answer suggests, there's a problem with dimensions, and that's exactly where I'm stuck.

More concretely, I have subspaces $U$ and $W$, $U$ has dimension 3, $W$ has dimension 2.  So that if I treat the vectors constituting their bases as column vectors of some matrix $M$, and  find $\textbf{kernel}(M)$, the kernel will contain vectors with 5 elements. I don't understand how to use this to find a basis of $U \cap W$, because that has vectors of a "wrong" shape...

And if this sounds too abstract, here's more concrete example.

Given $U = \textbf{span}\{(1,0,1,1), (0,1,0,-1), (1,0,1,0)\}$ and $W = \textbf{span}\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,-1,2)\}$, what is a basis of $U\cap W$? Also, what if $U$ was just one dimensional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the kernel of $M$ is still the right thing to do in this problem. The vectors in the kernel aren't vectors in $U\cap W$ though; as you correctly point out, they are in $\Bbb R^5$ while $U\cap W \subset \Bbb R^4$. Instead, the vectors in the kernel give you the coefficients for a linear combination of the basis vectors which is equal to a vector in $U\cap W$.

By way of example, the kernel of $M$ for the specific $U$ and $W$ you give above is $\textbf{span}\{(-3,-1,4,-1,1)\}$ In other words, $$-3(1,0,1,1) + -1(0,1,0,-1)+4(1,0,1,0)-1(1,0,0,0)+1(0,1,−1,2) = (0,0,0,0)$$ Therefore $$-3(1,0,1,1) + -1(0,1,0,-1)+4(1,0,1,0) = 1(1,0,0,0)-1(0,1,−1,2)$$ and therefore this vector is in $U\cap W$. In fact it spans $U\cap W$ since that intersection happens to be one-dimensional.

More generally, you would find a basis for the kernel of $M$, and for each basis vector, you would come up with a vector of $U\cap W$ in this fashion. The resulting vectors would be a basis of $U\cap W$.