# 2 questions on linear algebra. Would like to evaluate my answers.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> 1. Let us assume that matrix $B$ was created by deleting a number of rows and columns of matrix $A$. Does the rank of matrix $B$ can be larger than the rank of matrix $A$?

No, because some of them (rows and columns) could be dependent on each other, so deleting them may not decrease the rank of matrix.

> 2. Are there such subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^7$ that $dim(V_1 \cap V_2) = 2$ and $dim V_1 = dim V_2 = 5$ ?

No, there are not. For example: $V_1 = lin(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4, \alpha_5)$, $V_2 = lin(\alpha_3, \alpha_4, \alpha_5, \alpha_6, \alpha_7)$ For those $2$ $dim(V_1 \cap V_2) = 3$ and they allready "use up" all possible dimensions.

Comment: For 2. your argument is not clear. For an argument see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265341/calculating-dimension-of-the-intersection-of-two-subspaces).

Comment: Your argument for the first part isn't good either.  Arguing that it is possible that the rank not go down does not prove that the rank can not go up.

Comment: Ok, you are right. But it actually can't (which was not written in my answer), am I right?