# Find basis for intersection of span of vectors and equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have two subspaces $U=x_1+2x_2+x_3-3x_4+x_5=0$ and $V=\text{span}((1, 2, 0, 1, -1)^t, (-1, 0, 3, 2, 0)^t, (1, 0, 0, 0, 1)^t, (0, 2, -3, -1, -3))$

I rewrote $U$ as 
$
    \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
         -2 & -1 & 3 & -1 \\
         1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix} x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5
    \end{pmatrix}
$.

I also figured out that the last vector of $V$ is linearly dependent on the other three, so only the first three are necessary for the span, I put this into a matrix and performed row reduction:

$\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & -2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \lambda_3 \\ \lambda_4
\end{pmatrix}$

Then I tried inserting the vectors of $V$ into the equation for $U$ like so: $(\lambda_1 + \lambda_4)+2(\lambda_2-\lambda_4)+(\lambda_3-2\lambda_4)-3(0)+0=0$.  I then rewrote as
$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 \\
\lambda_2 \\
\lambda_3 \\
\lambda_4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\lambda_2
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
+ 
\lambda_3
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ 0 \\ 1\\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
+
\lambda_4
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
    -2 & -1 & 3 \\
    1  &  0 & 0 \\
    0  &  1 & 0 \\
    0  &  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_2 \\ \lambda_3 \\ \lambda_4
\end{pmatrix}$

And by rewriting into row-echelon form, I found that all three columns together form a basis for $U\cap V$.

But using this [suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1828391/307268), I found that the dimension of the intersection is 2, ( I put the first four (all of them) columns of the matrix in the rewritten $U$ form and the first three columns of the rewritten $V$ matrix next to each other and performed some row reduction) and found five pivot elements and two non-pivot variables, so I concluded that the dimension is two, in contradiction with all of the above.

**So my question is, is my thinking incorrect in that I can put the vectors of one subspace into the equation of another, or am I making a mistake here, or did I not correctly apply the suggested answer link?**

Comment: How are the columns of that last matrix a basis for any subspace of $\mathbb R^5$ when they’re not even elements of $\mathbb R^5$ in the first place?

Comment: @amd Hmm, U\cap V should indeed be a subspace of R^5, where is my analysis going wrong?