# Find basis of subspaces U+V and U∩V from span of V and U

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

You are given two vector subspaces U = span $\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 \cr 1 \cr 1 \cr 1 \cr 1\end{bmatrix} ,\begin{bmatrix} 1 \cr 0 \cr 0 \cr 0 \cr-1 \end{bmatrix} \right)$ and V = span $\left(\begin{bmatrix} -1 \cr -1 \cr0 \cr0\cr1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 3 \cr 2 \cr2 \cr 2\cr1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2 \cr 1\cr2\cr2\cr2 \end{bmatrix} \right)$.

How would you find the basis of U+V and the basis of U∩V?

I have problems with the linearly dependent vector in the span of V. When am I able to remove this vector and perform Gauss elimination of a 5x4 matrix instead of the whole 5x5 matrix (for the sum or intersection?)

Comment: One would apply the standard way, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25371/how-to-find-basis-for-intersection-of-two-vector-spaces-in-mathbbrn) for the intersection.

Comment: minor note: you shouldn't say "the" basis, for a basis of a vector space is (mostly) not unique.

Comment: Please show your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) to know how to ask a good question on this website. (Please take note that this website does **not** do your homework for you)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of many others already on this site. There are several examples of how to compute a basis for the intersection of subspaces in the handy list of related questions at right. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25371/265466 has a good description of the method.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani - "mostly"? Bases are never unique.

Comment: @PaulSinclair - that is not true. Consider any zero dimensional vector space. That only has $\emptyset$ as basis. If that doesn't satisfy you, you may consider $\mathbb F_2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ and see that it has a unique basis.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani - well, that's why I asked. You got me. There is one exception, or two depending on exactly how one defines "basis".